# Adding filepath to crystal reports based on parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a Crystal Report where all data that is displayed is based around the OrderNo. Each order has separate documents that are housed on the server (each order has different documents). What I'd like to be able to do is add a hyperlink to the report that will take the user to those specific documents when clicked (the file path will need to change dynamically based on the OrderNo).

If possible, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the field you wish to act as a hyperlink.
Select Format Field...
Go to the Hyperlink tab...

Comment: Forgot to mention, note that the hyperlink can be an expression, so it's easy to create a dynamic path.